# How can I create a custom contacts list in the background using the contacts_service package?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Some contacts have multiple phones so I need to flatten them, doing this in the main isolate makes the UI skip some frames. In my case, I have 1000+ contacts some with multiple phone numbers.

Versions:

```
contacts_service: ^0.6.1
```

I get the contacts using (Make sure persmissions have been accepted):

```
late Iterable<Contact> globalContacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
```

When creating this is when the screen stutters (createList resides outside the class):

```
List<K2PhoneContact>? createList(List<Contact> contacts) {
  final List<K2PhoneContact> k2PhoneContacts = [];
  contacts.forEach((contact) {
    contact.phones!.forEach((phone) {
    k2PhoneContacts.add(K2PhoneContact(
        initials: contact.initials(),
        displayName: contact.displayName,
        firstName: contact.givenName,
        lastName: contact.familyName,
        phoneNumber: 'phone.value'));
    k2Logger.d('_k2PhoneContacts givenName: ${contact.givenName} familyName: ${contact.familyName}');
     });
  });
  return k2PhoneContacts;
}

class _PayToMpesaViewState extends State<PayToMpesaView> {
  List<K2PhoneContact>? _k2PhoneContacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadContacts();
  }
  }

  Future<void> _loadContacts() async {
    final status = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      _requestPermission(Permission.contacts);
    }
    _k2PhoneContacts = [];
    _k2PhoneContacts = await compute(createList, globalContacts.toList());
  }
```

Error log:
[image]

Comment: Can you try with a `FutureBuilder` widget?, I think it handles it quite well

Comment: Tried using FutureBuilder, since it uses async it will still interfere with the main isolate making the screen stutter.